# jQuery/js wrap near div with same classes into single div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have the following structure and I need to wrap the `div` around `.item`.
In some place there is two items and in some place there is single item:

```
<div class="section">
  <div class="heading"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="heading"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="heading"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="heading"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

I need output in this format:

```
<div class="section">
  <div class="heading"></div>
  <div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="heading"></div>
  <div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="heading"></div>
  <div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="heading"></div>
  <div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried with the following code but it wraps all code to single class.

```
var classes = {};
$(".section > div").each(function() {
    classes[$(this).attr("class")] = true;
});
for (singleClass in classes) {
    $("." + singleClass).wrapAll('<div class="item" />');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop through `.heading` elements using `.each()` and in loop select `.item` that is next to each other using [`.nextUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) and then wrap them using `.wrapAll()`

```js
$(".heading").each(function(){
  $(this).nextUntil(".heading").wrapAll("<div></div>");
});
```

```css
.heading + div {background: #ccc}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section">
  <div class="heading">heading</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="heading">heading</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="heading">heading</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="heading">heading</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
let h,s= document.querySelector('.section');

[...s.children].forEach(e=>  {
  if(e.className=='heading') { 
    h=document.createElement("div")
    e.insertAdjacentElement('afterend',h)
  } else {
    h.appendChild(e)
  }
})
```

```js
function change() {
  let h,s= document.querySelector('.section');

  [...s.children].forEach(e=>  {
    if(e.className=='heading') { 
      h=document.createElement("div")
      e.insertAdjacentElement('afterend',h)
    } else {
      h.appendChild(e)
    }
  })
}
```

```css
div { margin-left: 30px;}
```

```html
<button onclick="change()">Click here to change</button>

<div class="section">
  <div class="heading">head 1</div>
  <div class="item">item 1</div>
  <div class="item">item 2</div>
  <div class="heading">head 2</div>
  <div class="item">item 3</div>
  <div class="item">item 4</div>
  <div class="heading">head 3</div>
  <div class="item">item 5</div>
  <div class="heading">head 4</div>
  <div class="item">item 6</div>
  <div class="item">item 7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Mohammad no - check in chrome console

Answer (score -1):

1. Use nextUntil() with warpAll()

```js
$(".heading").each(function() {
  $(this).nextUntil(".heading").wrapAll("<div class='red'></div>")
});
```

```css
.red {
  border: red 1px solid
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section">
  <div class="heading">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="heading">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="heading">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="heading">9</div>
  <div class="item">0</div>
  <div class="item">-</div>
</div>
```